# Bitnami Stack copying via SSH

Tags: php, centos

Hello Wonder if anybody can help. I'm new to SSH & linux, and going through setting up a server.

I'm picking up bits and bobs of bash ok, and remembered someone suggested using bitnami stack for an easier way to set up the server. Plus reading about it seems to have some good features.

So my server just has centos on at the moment, and I removed my previous dabblings with installing mysql/php etc, so I think it's pretty clean now.

I downloaded the bitnami stack for linux, the .run file, and as a first step now I'm trying to get it up there via ssh, it's in my c: on my local pc

I understand I use scp for this, but what's the correct syntax for getting this up there?

Thanks

Mro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single file to transfer, located in `C:\Myfile.zip`

```
scp c:\Myfile.zip username@webhost-name.com:.
```

If you have a whole directory you need to copy, located at `C:\MyDirectory\`

```
scp -r c:\MyDirectory\ username@webhost-name.com:.
```

Either command should prompt you to accept the hostkey for 'webhost-name.com', and enter the password for the 'username' account, and then transfer the files.  Replace `webhost-name` and `username` with the values for your environment.

Note the period `.` after the colon `:` on both commandlines, it specifies the username's remote home directory as the target location; if you wish a different remote path, replace the `.` with the required path.